# Question about transposing a square matrix

Tags: java, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have a simple question that I've tried whiteboarded multiple times but still can't understand. How come for the inner for loop, we have to set column = row + 1; I was under the impression you should initialize column = 0 and then simply just swap the row into columns and columns into rows for the transposing of the matrix, but I keep failing the test cases. Thank you

```
public static void transposeMatrix(int[][] matrix) {

    for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++)
    {
        for (int column = row + 1 ; column < matrix.length; column++)
        {

            int temp = matrix[row][column];
            matrix[row][column] = matrix[column][row];
            matrix[column][row] = temp;

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to swap the upper or lower triangle of the matrix once.

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

you consider 2, 3, 6 and swap it with 4, 7, 8 respectively. Diagonal does not need to be swapped. Hence you don't start with 0 always.

Comment: I see what you mean but how does the swap occur if when we are at the number "4" in your above matrix if it is located at row = 1 column = 0?  With column =  row + 1 means column would never be 0 so the swap for  "4" would never occur?

Comment: When you are at matrix[0][1] which is 2, you swap matrix[0][1] with matrix[1][0] which is 4, likewise with matrix[0][2] =3 swapped with matrix[2][0]=7. In this line `matrix[row][column] = matrix[column][row];` column is zero when row is zero